# How to create duplicate record for another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

In one project it is necessary to work with two databases. It is necessary to duplicate posts (table `posts`) from the "native" database to the secondary one. The database architecture is the same, but the projects are different.

Models for working with the "native" database are and are used as usual:

```
Post.all
```

Some of these models have been moved to the subdirectory:

```
Second::Post.all
```

Work with two databases was established. The project can create both "native" posts, and posts in the database of the second project.

But posts have associations. And these associations are nested. And this duplication in the project is applied in several places.

Therefore, there was a question in optimization. I already had experience with deep_cloneable gem, but it (like all known analogs to me) works with the original model. And I need to specify a custom model.

Tell me, please, the solution to this situation.